# Concentrating Isopropyl alchohol using non-iodized salt

Tags: concentration

I am using 99% isopropyl alchohol to clean soldering flux residues for my electronics projects. Due to a certain viruse running amok in the world today, I am not able to get from my usual supplier. I am running low on supplies. So i got this idea that i would concentrate the more common (but still not so easy to get in my area) 40% or 70% ispropyl alchohol.

Searching the internet on guides to do it, it would seem that there is an easy way to do it. According to this [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Concentrate-Rubbing-Alcohol-With-Table-Salt/); add non-iodized salt to the solution until its past its saturation point. By this time the heavier water should sink and the lighter isopropyl should float. Extracting it would now be easy with a syringe.

For my question. Water and especially salt is an enemy to any metal. I would like to ask if this process mixes tiny amount of salt to the isopropyl? if so by how much %? Is NaCl even soluble to isopropyl or are these just tiny particles floating around and if i leave the solution to settle for a longer period of time those particles would sink down. up until what percent can i bring the concentration to?

As for the Salt to use what other ingredients should i look out other than iodine( or other close sounding).

P.S. I am no chemist any way, the only chemistry background i have is during my high-school days. It was a time that i was still not able to appreciate class lessons. So go easy on me

Comment: I've never heard of adding salt to create two phases between water and isopropyl alcohol, but if you want to create concentrated isopropyl alcohol I'd suggest distillation. The alcohol should distill off before the water.

Comment: Anhydrous magnesium sulfate would do what you want

Comment: Or calcium sulfate; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_sulfate

Comment: @CH3M i have considered distillation at first since isopropyl boil at lower temp than water, but i found that guide on [instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Concentrate-Rubbing-Alcohol-With-Table-Salt/) which is a lot easier to do.

Comment: @Waylander and DrMoishePippik only easily bought items please :/ or do they have a laymans name :)

Comment: Waylander & DrMoishePippik - Both of those salts are hygroscopic. That doesn't seem to be a good thing on a circuit board.

Comment: Simple distillation won't work. From Wikipedia ["Isopropyl alcohol forms an azeotrope with water, which gives a boiling point of 80.37 °C (176.67 °F) and a composition of 87.7 wt% (91 vol%) isopropyl alcohol."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol#Properties) // So you could  dry over a salt, then distill to be sure that there were no particulates in the liquid.

Comment: Not a bad question, but all in all there is no "simple" way for a ordinary person without a lab to purify isopropyl alcohol. The chemicals and equipment needed will be a much greater expense than the isopropyl alcohol. Without a proper lab there is also a safety concern. Isopropyl alcohol is flammable.

Comment: Enough Mag Sulfate salts the water out from IPA to give a two phase system. It is more effective than NaCl

Comment: @Jakequin The typical path to dry isopropanol is 1) distilling this mixture of constant boiling temperature (aceotropic mixture) at 80C which is of 91% isopropanol which than 2) is boiled under reflux for hours with about 200g/L of Calciumoxide before this is distilled (Perrin, Purification of Laboratory Chemicals). _However_, according to https://www.all-electronics.de/wp-content/uploads/migrated/document/197287/infodirectkyzen.pdf -- written in English, with contact emails -- some modern flux residues are removed by dish washer and water, which could liberate you from isopropanol at all.

Comment: I did not read the pdf yet but, `are removed by dish washer and water` that does not sound instinctively right. although i can see it happening, since dishwashers mostly use hot water which could be enough to melt the flux and get removed by the water pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Common table salt can have additives, so I would recommend working with high purity Epsom Salts (magnesium sulfate hydrate). Heat to remove water of crystallization at 100 degrees Celsius for two hours.

Add your isopropyl alcohol with the MgSO4 in excess and wait until there is a separation. I would decant and allow for a safety margin above the visible separation line.

[Here is a reference](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/separate-liquids-with-salt/).

Comment: would the isopropyl contain any traces salt after the process?